# Texstudio Compilation error. please advise

Tags: installing, texstudio

Trying to compile a document but getting the this error: Could not start build &view: PdfLaTex: "C:/*/*/Programs/MikTex2.9/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe" -synctex=1- interaction=nonstopmode "doc ".tex

Comment: is NikTex2.9 correct ?

Comment: Sorry for that blunder:
Trying to compile a document but getting the this error: Could not start build &view: PdfLaTex: "C:///Programs/MikTex2.9/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe" -synctex=1- interaction=nonstopmode "doc ".tex

Comment: Both MikTex and TexLive are installed

Comment: so you have a pdflatex.exe in that folder?

Comment: pdflatex.exe is in that folder, yes

Comment: log says process started....Process exited with error(s)

Comment: let me reinstall and see how it works. it worked on the other machine but I don't understand what has happened this time. am sure this time it will work its a lovely software

Comment: now the user path in the user variables is pointing the bin; pdflatex.exe; latex.exe. the system variable path is pointing to the bin; pdflatex.exe. the system variable will not accept another addition to the path

Comment: working just deleted the texstudio.ini file and working perfectly. Cheers people of God for the help